# AngularFire2: Get User Property Value

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am trying to retrieve a property of a user profile in Firebase, using AngularFire2.

Just to be clear i am not trying to get the auth object, the user profile is a custom object i am storing in the database.  So essentially i am querying the auth object to get the userid, then querying the user object by userid to retrieve another property.

This is the code i have written but i only seem to be able to get access to the whole object, if i try the following i get a compile error on the accountId property.  Any guidance would be appreciated

```
constructor(
    private af: AngularFireDatabase,
    private _firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

    this.authProfile$ = afAuth.authState;
    this.authProfile$.subscribe((auth: firebase.User) => {
        if (auth) {
            this.loginId = auth.uid;
            this.af.list('users', {
                query: {
                    orderByChild: 'userId',
                    equalTo: this.loginId
                }
            }).subscribe((user) =>  {
                this.currentAccountId = user.accountId; //Compile error here
            })
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I worked out it was a simple mistake i was pulling back an array and trying to access property like a single object.

This worked:

```
constructor(
    private af: AngularFireDatabase,
    private _firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

    this.authProfile$ = afAuth.authState;
    this.authProfile$.subscribe((auth: firebase.User) => {
        if (auth) {
            this.loginId = auth.uid;
            this.af.list('users', {
                query: {
                    orderByChild: 'userId',
                    equalTo: this.loginId,
                    limitToFirst: 1
                }
            }).subscribe(user => {
                this.currentAccountId = user[0].accountId;
                console.log(this.currentAccountId);
            })
        }
    });
```